# Аналог CRON в android приложении

Tags: android, cron

Необходимо, чтобы приложение запускалось каждые пол-часа и проверяло обновления.

Через какой механизм это можно реализовать? Нужно что-то вроде CRON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) обеспечивает доступ к сервису планировки задач Android. Он регистрирует в системе интент и когда наступает обозначенное время запускает этот интент. Если момент вызова приложение закрыто, то оно будет вновь запущено.